# WordPress Customizer Selective Refresh: works only on first setting change

Tags: theme-customizer

I have created a new control (checkbox) in WP Customizer. The way it should work is as it follows: the corresponding section should display the last published post when the checkbox is checked (true) or a custom background image (and some content) when the checkbox is unchecked (false).

Everything works fine on first setting change. Let's say the input is unchecked on page load - the section will display a custom background image. If I check the checkbox the section refreshes and the last post gets displayed. Until here everything is fine.

But if I uncheck the checkbox (as a second action on same control) nothing happens. Still nothing on next checks/unchecks.

I don't have any JS related to this control (I've also removed all custom JS and the issue persists).

**customizer.php**

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'latest_post', 
                            array(
                                'default'    => "", 
                                'type'       => 'theme_mod',
                                'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
                                'transport'   => 'postMessage',
                            ) 
                        );
$wp_customize->add_control('latest_post', 
                            array(
                                'label'    => __( 'Header Content', 'mytheme' ),
                                'section'  => 'header_section',
                                'settings' => 'latest_post',
                                'type'     => 'checkbox'
                            )
                        );      
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'latest_post', array(
                            'selector'        => '.header-section',
                            'render_callback' => 'header_markup'
                        ) );



function header_markup(){
  $latest_post = get_theme_mod('latest_post');

  switch($latest_post):
     case true:
        return "latest post";
     case false:
        return "custom media";
     default:
        return "custom media";
  endswitch;

}
```

**html**

```
<div class="header-section">
   <php echo header_markup(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine the actual value being returned from the checkbox, using `var_dump()`. It looks like it is not matching `true` or `false`, but always falling through to the default case. 
Even your default value of "" is not `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Joy. I've checked and it does return true/false (boolean), but the section refreshes just on first change. Then... nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I believe is that your setting is getting saved as a string instead of a boolean. You need to supply a `sanitize_callback` when registering the setting to ensure it is saved as such.

I believe this should do it:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'latest_post',
    array(
        'default'           => false,
        'type'              => 'theme_mod',
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_validate_boolean', // 
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Weston. I've tried that too, but still nothing. I've also used your plugin (Customizer Dev Tools) and it looks like the value is updating in WordPress, but the section is not refreshing.
`[customizer.pane.setting.change] latest_post 
- true
+ false
base.js:117:4
[customizer.preview.setting.change]  latest_post 
- true
+ false
base.js:117:4
[customizer.pane.setting.change]  latest_post 
- false
+ true
base.js:117:4
[customizer.preview.setting.change]  latest_post 
- false
+ true`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the selectors in the add_partial method and the preview js file do not match!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the selective_refresh array:

```
'container_inclusive' => true,
```

This helped for me.

Post is from a long time ago.. but you never know if other ppl run into the same problem.